# Adding constraint to an association

Tags: jpa, playframework, jpa-2.0

Here is the deal I have a one to many relationship between User and Post

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Post.class, mappedBy = "author")
  @OrderBy("createdAt DESC")
  public List<Post> posts;
...
}

@Entity
public class Post extends Model {
...
  public int privacy; // 0=public, 1=private
  @ManyToOne
  public User author;
...
}
```

Works beautifully... Now I want to retrieve the public posts from the users? Of course iterating over the result and deleting the private posts is not an option, I ultimately need to do some pagination, and that would become a headache. Is there some annotation that could help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
User author = User.findById(1);  
int pageNumber = 1;
int pageSize = 10;
Post.find("FROM Post WHERE author = ? AND privacy = 0", author).fetch(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it. I'm used to the rails' scopes. But JPA is not as flexible as ActiveRecord unfortunatly